# Visual Studio VB pretty listing settings

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, editor, notation

Does anyone know how to stop Visual Studio VB.NET editor from changing my beautiful scientific notation numbers into hideous decimal notation?

It seems that this is part of "Pretty Listing" (single checkbox in the options). I'd like to keep the other features of pretty listing, I just don't want to have to stare at 0.0000000000000001 when I could be looking at 1e-16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do it. You could rely on the implicit `CDbl()` conversion in this situation:

```
Dim myPrettyNumber As Double = "1E-16"
```

Or if you just want to be able to read it more easily, add a comment:

```
Dim myUglyNumber As Double = 0.0000000000000001 ' 1E-16
```

Comment: Well, since I always work with Option Strict On, the implicit conversion won't kick in. Sounds like I'm screwed then. The best solution is probably defining some constants somewhere...

Comment: Never never ever use implicit conversion, it's regionally aware and it means your program will only work on certain locales. In this case just use `Val("1E-16")` which is not regionally aware and will always work.

Comment: ...I was just throwing out some options -- I never claimed they were _good_ options! :)

Answer (score 1):

**You may turn pretty listing back on after defining your constants.**

Visual Basic won't obfuscate numbers that have already been defined so long as you don't modify the lines that they're on. If you accidentally do modify a line being forced to scientific notation Visual basic will only convert that line to use fixed notation.

Obviously this works best for the declaration of constants or formula's that won't change very often. It is less viable otherwise.

Comment: Interesting idea. It does work as long as I remember to keep my grubby hands away from Ctrl+k, Ctrl+D as well...

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in VB to turn off "pretty listing":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y0y5th94.aspx