# Prevent Visual Basic from converting scientific notation constants to fixed notation

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual Studio VB pretty listing settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020615/visual-studio-vb-pretty-listing-settings)

Each time I write:

`Dim foo As Double = 1E-9`

Visual Studio / Visual Basic rewrites the line to read

`Dim foo As Double = 0.000000001`

**How do I go about preventing Visual Studio / Visual Basics's auto-formatting to so that I may store these numbers in scientific notation?**

PS: Visual Studio / Visual Basic doesn't convert to fixed notation when the exponent is either greater than 14 or less than -16.

Please note that this question has NOTHING to do with how this number is displayed to users of the compiled application but instead the visual representation within the source code.

Comment: Tools + Options, Text Editor, Basic, VB Specific, turn off the "Pretty listing" option.

Comment: Shame on you for not mentioning that you already knew this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12413946/17034

Comment: I found the other question after having asked it here. It did not show up in my original search as the wording was significantly different. With the additional knowledge of the pretty listing option and a bit of experimentation I came to the answer I posted there and flagged this question as a duplicate. It appears as though this question has not yet been closed.